# Installing Docker for Windows 10, 32 Bit

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to install Docker for Windows 10 Pro, 32bits but unfortunately, I get this message

"Looks like something went wrong in step 'Chekibg if machine default exists' Press any key to continue ...'"

When i press the enter key its exists

Please help

Comment: did you  Enable Hyper-V for Docker ?

Comment: Hello Osamazx. I doubt if I did but can you please tell me how it can be done. Thanks

Comment: Sure, first of all you need to make sure that Virtualization must be enabled on your machine (BIOS setting) once you are doning this there some changes you have to do check this link here https://www.dockerjet.com/how-to-install-docker-on-windows

Comment: Hello Osamazx. This worked and thanks a lot. You are appreciated